# How to make this picture slider puzzle start shuffling without button press?

Tags: javascript

Goodday Coders, Im struggling with this puzzle script that I want to use for a website's "meet the team" page.

I would like the puzzle to scramble as the page loads instead of having to press the shuffle button.
If people press the "Wie ben ik" button, the puzzle should solve, like it is doing right now.

Somehow I cant get it to work, it would be great if someone could help me out.

Here's the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/verberne/pen/WNxyprV

```js
// Begin game once DOM loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", game);
// document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", shuffleTimeouts);

function game() {

  // Data structure to hold positions of tiles
  var parentX = document.querySelector(".sliding-puzzle").clientHeight;
  var baseDistance = 38;
  var tileMap = {
    1: {
      tileNumber: 1,
      position: 1,
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    2: {
      tileNumber: 2,
      position: 2,
      top: 0,
      left: baseDistance * 1
    },
    3: {
      tileNumber: 3,
      position: 3,
      top: 0,
      left: baseDistance * 2
    },
    4: {
      tileNumber: 4,
      position: 4,
      top: baseDistance,
      left: 0
    },
    5: {
      tileNumber: 5,
      position: 5,
      top: baseDistance,
      left: baseDistance
    },
    6: {
      tileNumber: 6,
      position: 6,
      top: baseDistance,
      left: baseDistance * 2
    },
    7: {
      tileNumber: 7,
      position: 7,
      top: baseDistance * 2,
      left: 0
    },
    8: {
      tileNumber: 8,
      position: 8,
      top: baseDistance * 2,
      left: baseDistance
    },
    empty: {
      position: 9,
      top: baseDistance * 2,
      left: baseDistance * 2
    }
  }

  // Array of tileNumbers in order of last moved
  var history = [];

  // Movement map
  function movementMap(position) {
    if (position == 9) return [6, 8];
    if (position == 8) return [5, 7, 9];
    if (position == 7) return [4, 8];
    if (position == 6) return [3, 5, 9];
    if (position == 5) return [2, 4, 6, 8];
    if (position == 4) return [1, 5, 7];
    if (position == 3) return [2, 6];
    if (position == 2) return [1, 3, 5];
    if (position == 1) return [2, 4];
  }

  // Board setup according to the tileMap
  document.querySelector('#shuffle').addEventListener('click', shuffle, true);
  document.querySelector('#solve').addEventListener('click', solve, true);
  var tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');
  var delay = -50;
  for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    tiles[i].addEventListener('click', tileClicked, true);

    var tileId = tiles[i].innerHTML;
    delay += 50;
    setTimeout(setup, delay, tiles[i]);
  }

  function setup(tile) {
    var tileId = tile.innerHTML;
    // tile.style.left = tileMap[tileId].left + '%';
    // tile.style.top = tileMap[tileId].top + '%';
    var xMovement = parentX * (tileMap[tileId].left / 100);
    var yMovement = parentX * (tileMap[tileId].top / 100);
    var translateString = "translateX(" + xMovement + "px) " + "translateY(" + yMovement + "px)"
    tile.style.webkitTransform = translateString;
    recolorTile(tile, tileId);
  }

  function tileClicked(event) {
    var tileNumber = event.target.innerHTML;
    moveTile(event.target);

    if (checkSolution()) {
      console.log("You win!");
    }
  }

  // Moves tile to empty spot
  // Returns error message if tile cannot be moved
  function moveTile(tile, recordHistory = true) {
    // Check if Tile can be moved 
    // (must be touching empty tile)
    // (must be directly perpendicular to empty tile)
    var tileNumber = tile.innerHTML;
    if (!tileMovable(tileNumber)) {
      console.log("Tile " + tileNumber + " can't be moved.");
      return;
    }

    // Push to history
    if (recordHistory == true) {

      if (history.length >= 3) {
        if (history[history.length - 1] != history[history.length - 3]) history.push(tileNumber);
      } else {
        history.push(tileNumber);
      }
    }

    // Swap tile with empty tile
    var emptyTop = tileMap.empty.top;
    var emptyLeft = tileMap.empty.left;
    var emptyPosition = tileMap.empty.position;
    tileMap.empty.top = tileMap[tileNumber].top;
    tileMap.empty.left = tileMap[tileNumber].left;
    tileMap.empty.position = tileMap[tileNumber].position;

    // tile.style.top = emptyTop  + '%'; 
    // tile.style.left = emptyLeft  + '%';

    var xMovement = parentX * (emptyLeft / 100);
    var yMovement = parentX * (emptyTop / 100);
    var translateString = "translateX(" + xMovement + "px) " + "translateY(" + yMovement + "px)"
    tile.style.webkitTransform = translateString;

    tileMap[tileNumber].top = emptyTop;
    tileMap[tileNumber].left = emptyLeft;
    tileMap[tileNumber].position = emptyPosition;

    recolorTile(tile, tileNumber);
  }


  // Determines whether a given tile can be moved
  function tileMovable(tileNumber) {
    var selectedTile = tileMap[tileNumber];
    var emptyTile = tileMap.empty;
    var movableTiles = movementMap(emptyTile.position);

    if (movableTiles.includes(selectedTile.position)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }



  }

  // Returns true/false based on if the puzzle has been solved
  function checkSolution() {
    if (tileMap.empty.position !== 9) return false;

    for (var key in tileMap) {
      if ((key != 1) && (key != "empty")) {
        if (tileMap[key].position < tileMap[key - 1].position) return false;
      }
    }

    // Clear history if solved
    history = [];
    return true;
  }

  // Check if tile is in correct place!
  function recolorTile(tile, tileId) {
    if (tileId == tileMap[tileId].position) {
      tile.classList.remove("error");
    } else {
      tile.classList.add("error");
    }
  }


  // Shuffles the current tiles
  shuffleTimeouts = [];

  function shuffle() {
    clearTimers(solveTimeouts);
    var boardTiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');
    var shuffleDelay = 200;
    shuffleLoop();

    var shuffleCounter = 0;
    while (shuffleCounter < 20) {
      shuffleDelay += 200;
      shuffleTimeouts.push(setTimeout(shuffleLoop, shuffleDelay));
      shuffleCounter++;
    }
  }

  var lastShuffled;

  function shuffleLoop() {
    var emptyPosition = tileMap.empty.position;
    var shuffleTiles = movementMap(emptyPosition);
    var tilePosition = shuffleTiles[Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffleTiles.length))];
    var locatedTile;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      if (tileMap[i].position == tilePosition) {
        var locatedTileNumber = tileMap[i].tileNumber;
        locatedTile = tiles[locatedTileNumber - 1];
      }
    }
    if (lastShuffled != locatedTileNumber) {
      moveTile(locatedTile);
      lastShuffled = locatedTileNumber;
    } else {
      shuffleLoop();
    }

  }


  function clearTimers(timeoutArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < timeoutArray.length; i++) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutArray[i])
    }
  }

  // Temporary function for solving puzzle.
  // To be reimplemented with a more sophisticated algorithm
  solveTimeouts = []

  function solve() {
    clearTimers(shuffleTimeouts);


    repeater = history.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < repeater; i++) {
      console.log("started");
      solveTimeouts.push(setTimeout(moveTile, i * 100, tiles[history.pop() - 1], false));
    }
  }



}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  khtml-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure {
  margin: auto;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  padding-bottom: 50vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure a#shuffle {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure a#solve {
  color: #3498DB;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 00;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
  border: 18px solid #2C3E50;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle .tile {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://simonwiddowson.typepad.com/files/countryside360x360.jpg);
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle .tile.error {
  background-color: #F0867D;
}

#tile1 {
  background-position: left top;
}

#tile2 {
  background-position: center top;
}

#tile3 {
  background-position: right top;
}

#tile4 {
  background-position: left center;
}

#tile5 {
  background-position: center center;
}

#tile6 {
  background-position: right center;
}

#tile7 {
  background-position: left bottom;
}

#tile8 {
  background-position: center bottom;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .sliding-puzzle-figure {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
  .sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle {
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 14px;
  }
  .sliding-puzzle-figure .tile {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">


<figure class="sliding-puzzle-figure">

  <div class="sliding-puzzle">
    <div class="tile" id="tile1">1</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile2">2</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile3">3</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile4">4</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile5">5</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile6">6</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile7">7</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile8">8</div>
  </div>

  <figcaption><br><br> Barry Paling&nbsp; | <a id="shuffle">Shuffle</a> | <a id="solve">Wie ben ik</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Add 
```document.querySelector('#shuffle').click()```
to line no.274

Comment: You are welcome Kevin!!

Answer (score 2):

You call game on load, remove the shuffle click and just call shuffle() at the end of game() :

```
window.addEventListener("load",game);
function game() {
  ...
  shuffle();
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load",game);

function game() {
  // Data structure to hold positions of tiles
  var parentX = document.querySelector(".sliding-puzzle").clientHeight;
  var baseDistance = 38;
  var tileMap = {
    1: {
      tileNumber: 1,
      position: 1,
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    2: {
      tileNumber: 2,
      position: 2,
      top: 0,
      left: baseDistance * 1
    },
    3: {
      tileNumber: 3,
      position: 3,
      top: 0,
      left: baseDistance * 2
    },
    4: {
      tileNumber: 4,
      position: 4,
      top: baseDistance,
      left: 0
    },
    5: {
      tileNumber: 5,
      position: 5,
      top: baseDistance,
      left: baseDistance
    },
    6: {
      tileNumber: 6,
      position: 6,
      top: baseDistance,
      left: baseDistance * 2
    },
    7: {
      tileNumber: 7,
      position: 7,
      top: baseDistance * 2,
      left: 0
    },
    8: {
      tileNumber: 8,
      position: 8,
      top: baseDistance * 2,
      left: baseDistance
    },
    empty: {
      position: 9,
      top: baseDistance * 2,
      left: baseDistance * 2
    }
  }

  // Array of tileNumbers in order of last moved
  var history = [];

  // Movement map
  function movementMap(position) {
    if (position == 9) return [6, 8];
    if (position == 8) return [5, 7, 9];
    if (position == 7) return [4, 8];
    if (position == 6) return [3, 5, 9];
    if (position == 5) return [2, 4, 6, 8];
    if (position == 4) return [1, 5, 7];
    if (position == 3) return [2, 6];
    if (position == 2) return [1, 3, 5];
    if (position == 1) return [2, 4];
  }

  // Board setup according to the tileMap
  document.querySelector('#solve').addEventListener('click', solve, true);
  var tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');
  var delay = -50;
  for (var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
    tiles[i].addEventListener('click', tileClicked, true);

    var tileId = tiles[i].innerHTML;
    delay += 50;
    setTimeout(setup, delay, tiles[i]);
  }

  function setup(tile) {
    var tileId = tile.innerHTML;
    // tile.style.left = tileMap[tileId].left + '%';
    // tile.style.top = tileMap[tileId].top + '%';
    var xMovement = parentX * (tileMap[tileId].left / 100);
    var yMovement = parentX * (tileMap[tileId].top / 100);
    var translateString = "translateX(" + xMovement + "px) " + "translateY(" + yMovement + "px)"
    tile.style.webkitTransform = translateString;
    recolorTile(tile, tileId);
  }

  function tileClicked(event) {
    var tileNumber = event.target.innerHTML;
    moveTile(event.target);

    if (checkSolution()) {
      console.log("You win!");
    }
  }

  // Moves tile to empty spot
  // Returns error message if tile cannot be moved
  function moveTile(tile, recordHistory = true) {
    // Check if Tile can be moved 
    // (must be touching empty tile)
    // (must be directly perpendicular to empty tile)
    var tileNumber = tile.innerHTML;
    if (!tileMovable(tileNumber)) {
      console.log("Tile " + tileNumber + " can't be moved.");
      return;
    }

    // Push to history
    if (recordHistory == true) {

      if (history.length >= 3) {
        if (history[history.length - 1] != history[history.length - 3]) history.push(tileNumber);
      } else {
        history.push(tileNumber);
      }
    }

    // Swap tile with empty tile
    var emptyTop = tileMap.empty.top;
    var emptyLeft = tileMap.empty.left;
    var emptyPosition = tileMap.empty.position;
    tileMap.empty.top = tileMap[tileNumber].top;
    tileMap.empty.left = tileMap[tileNumber].left;
    tileMap.empty.position = tileMap[tileNumber].position;

    // tile.style.top = emptyTop  + '%'; 
    // tile.style.left = emptyLeft  + '%';

    var xMovement = parentX * (emptyLeft / 100);
    var yMovement = parentX * (emptyTop / 100);
    var translateString = "translateX(" + xMovement + "px) " + "translateY(" + yMovement + "px)"
    tile.style.webkitTransform = translateString;

    tileMap[tileNumber].top = emptyTop;
    tileMap[tileNumber].left = emptyLeft;
    tileMap[tileNumber].position = emptyPosition;

    recolorTile(tile, tileNumber);
  }


  // Determines whether a given tile can be moved
  function tileMovable(tileNumber) {
    var selectedTile = tileMap[tileNumber];
    var emptyTile = tileMap.empty;
    var movableTiles = movementMap(emptyTile.position);

    if (movableTiles.includes(selectedTile.position)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }



  }

  // Returns true/false based on if the puzzle has been solved
  function checkSolution() {
    if (tileMap.empty.position !== 9) return false;

    for (var key in tileMap) {
      if ((key != 1) && (key != "empty")) {
        if (tileMap[key].position < tileMap[key - 1].position) return false;
      }
    }

    // Clear history if solved
    history = [];
    return true;
  }

  // Check if tile is in correct place!
  function recolorTile(tile, tileId) {
    if (tileId == tileMap[tileId].position) {
      tile.classList.remove("error");
    } else {
      tile.classList.add("error");
    }
  }


  // Shuffles the current tiles
  shuffleTimeouts = [];

  function shuffle() {
    clearTimers(solveTimeouts);
    var boardTiles = document.querySelectorAll('.tile');
    var shuffleDelay = 200;
    shuffleLoop();

    var shuffleCounter = 0;
    while (shuffleCounter < 20) {
      shuffleDelay += 200;
      shuffleTimeouts.push(setTimeout(shuffleLoop, shuffleDelay));
      shuffleCounter++;
    }
  }

  var lastShuffled;

  function shuffleLoop() {
    var emptyPosition = tileMap.empty.position;
    var shuffleTiles = movementMap(emptyPosition);
    var tilePosition = shuffleTiles[Math.floor(Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffleTiles.length))];
    var locatedTile;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      if (tileMap[i].position == tilePosition) {
        var locatedTileNumber = tileMap[i].tileNumber;
        locatedTile = tiles[locatedTileNumber - 1];
      }
    }
    if (lastShuffled != locatedTileNumber) {
      moveTile(locatedTile);
      lastShuffled = locatedTileNumber;
    } else {
      shuffleLoop();
    }

  }


  function clearTimers(timeoutArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < timeoutArray.length; i++) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutArray[i])
    }
  }

  // Temporary function for solving puzzle.
  // To be reimplemented with a more sophisticated algorithm
  solveTimeouts = []

  function solve() {
    clearTimers(shuffleTimeouts);


    repeater = history.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < repeater; i++) {
      solveTimeouts.push(setTimeout(moveTile, i * 100, tiles[history.pop() - 1], false));
    }
  }
  shuffle()  
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  khtml-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure {
  margin: auto;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  padding-bottom: 50vh;
  padding-top: 10vh;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure a#shuffle {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure a#solve {
  color: #3498DB;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 00;
  width: 360px;
  height: 360px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
  border: 18px solid #2C3E50;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2C3E50;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle .tile {
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://simonwiddowson.typepad.com/files/countryside360x360.jpg);
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle .tile.error {
  background-color: #F0867D;
}

#tile1 {
  background-position: left top;
}

#tile2 {
  background-position: center top;
}

#tile3 {
  background-position: right top;
}

#tile4 {
  background-position: left center;
}

#tile5 {
  background-position: center center;
}

#tile6 {
  background-position: right center;
}

#tile7 {
  background-position: left bottom;
}

#tile8 {
  background-position: center bottom;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .sliding-puzzle-figure {
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
  .sliding-puzzle-figure .sliding-puzzle {
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 14px;
  }
  .sliding-puzzle-figure .tile {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

<figure class="sliding-puzzle-figure">

  <div class="sliding-puzzle">
    <div class="tile" id="tile1">1</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile2">2</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile3">3</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile4">4</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile5">5</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile6">6</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile7">7</div>
    <div class="tile" id="tile8">8</div>
  </div>

  <figcaption><br><br> Barry Paling&nbsp; |  <a id="solve">Wie ben ik</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thank you so much mplungjan! You've really helped me out here. Real heroes dont wear capes;)